# Xamarin Intent null pointer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello I'm trying to make a html file on Xamarin. After making the file I then try to open it up with intent but I keep getting a null pointer (**Java.Lang.NullPointerException**).

Is it because the intent in a different class?  I try to implementing the intent in the invoicePage.xaml.cs but whenever I call the StartActivity(intent) I kept getting formatting errors.

My code is as follow:

invoicePage.xaml.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace AIFieldService.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class InvoicePage : ContentPage
    {
        public InvoicePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
            htmlSource.Html =
              @"<html>
                <body>
                    <h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
                    <p>Welcome to WebView.</p>
                </body>
            </html>";
            web.Source = htmlSource;
        }

        public async void OnCancelClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }

        public void OnPrintClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           htmlMaker hm = new htmlMaker(web.Source.ToString());
           hm.write();
        }
    }
}
```

htmlMaker.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace AIFieldService
{
    [Activity(Label = "LaunchFileActivity")]
    public class htmlMaker : Activity
    {
        public string html = "";

        public htmlMaker()
        {
            html = "";
        }

        public htmlMaker(string h)
        {
            html = h;
        }


        public void write()
        {


            //This gets the full path for the "files" directory of your app, where you have permission to read/write.
            var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

            //This creates the full file path to file
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, "invoice.html");

            //Check if file is there
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                //Now create the file.
                var create = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);


                create.Dispose();
            }


            //writes to file
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, html);


            //opens file
            Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(filePath);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);

            //error------------------------------------
            this.StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So how is your solution set up? It seems you are mixing platform specific Android code with Xamarin.Forms code? Is that, at its base, a Xamarin.Forms app or an Android app that is using Xamarin.Forms pages?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms app,  When I was looking online this is what most people were doing to open up the browser on their app with Xamarin.

Comment: Maybe with Xamarin Android, with Xamarin.Forms it would need to be done differently. So that explains why you are mixing platform agnostic Xam.Forms code with platform specific Xamarin.Android code.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to separate your Forms code from your Android code, and yes one aspect of the issue you are facing is likely because the `htmlMaker` activity was not created properly by the Android OS. One should never use `new MyActivity()` to instantiate an activity class because the OS will not call the `OnCreate`, etc methods.

What I would suggest is to use a [Dependency Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) or [Messaging Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to call into the Android project code from the Forms shared code so you can run Android Specific code to write the file and open the browser. I am going to use Messaging Center as it is simpler. So starting from your `OnPrintClicked` handler:

```
public void OnPrintClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessagingCenter.Send<InvoicePage, string>(this, "html", web.Source.ToString());
}
```

Then in `MainActivity.OnCreate` method in the Android project, add the following:

```
Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Subscribe<InvoicePage, string>(this, "html", (sender, html) => 
    {
        //I changed this path to be a public path so external apps can access the file. 
        //Otherwise you would have to grant Chrome access to your private app files
        var documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments).AbsolutePath;
        Directory.CreateDirectory(documentsPath);

        //This creates the full file path to file
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, "invoice.html");

        //writes to file (no need to create it first as the below will create if necessary)
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, html);

        //opens file
        Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(filePath));

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        intent.SetClassName("com.android.chrome", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");

        this.StartActivity(intent);
    });
```

Comment: On the intent part how can you expose out side the app.  When I run the code i get ` [file path] exposed beyond app through `Intent.getData()`.  I was reading something about `<provider>` in the **AndroidManfest.xml**, but dont know how that would look like for this with the path being `Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments).AbsolutePath;`.

Comment: What do you mean "expose outside of the app"? A Provider allows other apps to get data from your app. How do you intend to tell a browser app to use your content provider? Here are docs on setting up a ContentProvider in your app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/content-providers/

Comment: Also I verified that the above code works to open the html file in the Chrome browser.

Comment: it works for creating the html file but when I run the app it keeps giving me `[file path] exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()`  when it gets to the `this.StartActivity(intent);`

Comment: I am not getting that, are you using the exact code above?

Comment: Is Google Chrome installed in your device?